# All Marketing Definitions get deleted from Secondary reporting database after rebuilding Reporting DB

Tags: xdb, reporting, marketing-definitions

When I run the `rebuildreportingdb.aspx` tool, it deletes all existing marketing definitions (Segments, GoalDefinitions, etc. tables) from secondary reporting database. I came to know about this after checking logs as below:

```
[Experience Analytics]: SegmentProcessor cannot execute. No segments were found
```

Before running this, I am deploying all marketing definitions, and they exist on both Primary and Secondary databases. MongoDB is also connected to the instance.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

that is exactly what should happen. It's part of the notes on the official rebuild reporting database instructions (https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/setting_up_and_maintaining/xdb/server_considerations/walkthrough_rebuilding_the_reporting_database):

> When you run the rebuild process (synchronization), this erases all information in the Sitecore_Reporting_Secondary database. Therefore, you should always use a clean copy of the database when you rebuild the reporting database because this speeds up the rebuild process and uses fewer resources.